# Where can I find the ground service manuals for the Bombardier BD-700 Global 5000?

Tags: bombardier

I am looking looking for a comprehensive ground service instructions memo/manual for Bombardier BD-700 Global 5000 which deals with the potable water and waste systems and GPU connection. Where can I find such manuals?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! This something you should probably get from the manufacturer or a professional mechanic. I'd be surprised to find it on the internet.

Comment: I second that.  If it's for personal reference, you may be able to turn up such a document using Google.  If it is for professional use you MUST consult with an OEM approved document for this purpose.

Comment: Most of these manuals are copyrighted and not available (legally) publicly. You will have to contact Bombardier or an authorized service center for the manuals (and probably pay for them).

Answer (score 2):

Bombardier offers these manuals through their [Technical Publications department](https://customer.aero.bombardier.com/cic/public/!ut/p/kcxml/04_Sj9SPykssy0xPLMnMz0vM0Y_QjzKLN4n38gLJgFme-pHIIgbxjnCBcP0ouPIouPIomLIgfW99X4_83FT9AP2C3NAIg8yAdEdHRUUAj61eXg!!/delta/base64xml/L3dJdyEvd0ZNQUFzQUsvNElVRS82XzRfSks!).

For your purposes, the following product may suit your needs:

> **Ground Handling, Servicing and Emergency Information Booklets**
>   These booklets are designed to provide information to personnel that
>   are not necessarily familiar with BBAS aircraft, but are called upon
>   to provide servicing or emergency service (e.g. fire fighters).
>   Included in the booklet is a general description of the aircraft,
>   towing, jacking and servicing information, danger areas, explosive
>   hazards, egress information, fire fighting information and emergency
>   lifting instructions.

Alternately, you may wish to have more detailed servicing instructions, which should be found in the Service Manual:

> **Maintenance Manuals and Service Manuals**
>   The manuals contain the information necessary for a trained mechanic to perform servicing,
>   fault isolation (trouble shooting) and functional testing of various
>   systems. It also includes information necessary for the mechanic to
>   perform maintenance on the aircraft at the Line Replaceable Unit (LRU)
>   level which includes removal and installation, adjustment, cleaning,
>   painting and minor repairs.

Comment: Thanks, we got all these, but the information on Potable Water, Waste and GPU connections is very scant (to say the least)...